# Make MaterialTopTabNavigator not visible

Tags: typescript, react-native

Does anyone know a way to make the react native MaterialTopTabNavigator not visible on the screen? I want the swiping functionality to go between screens, but I do not want to be able to see the actual tab navigator.

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen2" tabBarPosition="bottom">
        <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Material Top Tabs, you should be able to set `tabBar` to return an empty View. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator#tabbar

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={() => <View /> >
```

This will still keep the swipe behaviour you are expecting while hiding away the visible tabs.

Comment: tabBarVisible is not a prop in materialTopTabNavigator or else I would have used it. You are looking at documentation for bottom-tab-navigator

Comment: And while one can argue that I should just use bottom-tab-navigator if it will not be seen, however that does not have swiping functionality or else I would have just done that.

Comment: Oh got it. I was thinking of the wrong tab bar. In this case, you can set the `tabBar` property to return an empty view. I will update the answer.

Comment: @BestFromAbove Great to hear. Please mark the question as solved.